# insert sql records

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a data like

```
1
2
1
1
2
2
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```

I need to order the data like

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

the 3rd row "1" and the 5th row "2" should be ordered. Likewise 7th row "1" and the 10th row "2", 8th row "1" and the 11th row "2" etc.

In general, if the continuous count of "1" is 5, there will be 5 records with the value "2". 1->6,2->7,3->8 likewise it should be ordered.

Can you please tell me the logic in sql query? thanks in advance.

Comment: Here the numbers are showing as column, but each "1" and "2" is one of the cell in the row.

Comment: SQL has tables, rows and columns. (No records or cells.)

Comment: "the 3rd row .." - a row has no position in the sql table. One can `order  by` the rows in the query only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by col order by col);
```

If you have an ordering that you want between groups, then use that for the `order by` in the windowing clause.

Comment: Does this work on any DBMS ? The question wasn't tagged on a specific one (I guess this won't work on MySQL 5)

Comment: @Cid . . . It will work on any database that supports the standard `row_number()` functionality, which is almost all of them nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms supports window functions you can order 1s and 2s this way

```
select col 
from tbl
order by 2*row_number() over(partition by col order by col) + case col when 1 then 0 else 1 end;
```

but there is no way to tell where was any row in the query result in the source, `insert into tbl(col) values (1),(1),...` statement for example.

Comment: Thanks Serg. Actually it didn't work. Ok let me change the question in this way, Is it possible to add a column called rownumber in the existing table that has data? My rownumber order should be based on order of 3 columns.

Comment: @Peak , Please ask another question showing relevant table ddl and sample data. Most probably the answer is yes, but we need more info to be sure.

Comment: I have a table that has 3 columns. Product,Name,TimeStamp. At present, I dont have any rownumber column. If I fetch the record from the table I will be using
select * from table order by Product,Name,TimeStamp.

I will be getting some order of data. In that order I need another column that should show the row number. In simple I need a column that should tell me the row number based on the above order by query. 

Is it possible to insert values based on some order? while creating table like that? thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Peak , Please ask it as another question, not a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006082/sql-query-with-order-by-clause

Comment: OPERATOR PRODUCT USER NAME TIME STAMP
1 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 09:02:33.000
1 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 10:46:17.000
2 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 11:01:28.000
2 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 17:07:47.000

I have data like this. If the operator is 1, then the license is been purchased at the respective timestamp. If the operator is 2 then the license is released. Here for the 1st license, the 3rd row is the release time and for the 2nd purchased license, 4th row is the release time. I need data to be in this order 1st row, 3rd row, 2nd row and 4th row. Please help.