# SQL query with order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has 3 columns. Product,Name,TimeStamp. At present, I don't have any rownumber column. If I fetch the record from the table, I will be using

```
select * 
from table 
order by Product,Name,TimeStamp.
```

I will get some order of data. In that order I need another column that should show the row number. Simply put, I need a column that should tell me the row number based on the above order by query.

Is it possible to insert values based on some order? while creating table like that?

```
OPERATOR    PRODUCT USER NAME   TIME STAMP
1           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 09:02:33.000
1           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 10:46:17.000
2           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 11:01:28.000
2           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 17:07:47.000
```

Here if the operator is 1, license for product INS1 is taken and if the operator is 2 then the license for the same product is been returned. Same person can take more licenses. 1st row has the details of license been taken and the same license been returned and that information is stored in the 3rd row. for the 2nd row, the license returned information is stored in the 4th row.

I need to show the table like

```
OPERATOR    PRODUCT USER NAME   TIME STAMP
1           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 09:02:33.000
2           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 11:01:28.000
1           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 10:46:17.000
2           INS1    1YHS        2018-08-15 17:07:47.000
```

Comment: What dbms are you using ?

Comment: It is possible but the solution is very different depending on your DB engine.

Comment: I am using SQL server 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Transaction'  is a pair of take + return. It's identity is computed from source data so `OPERATOR`s could be grouped the way you need. The query may fail on data with unpaired `OPERATOR`s.

```
declare @tbl table (
OPERATOR int,   
PRODUCT varchar(50), 
[USER NAME] varchar(100),    
[TIME STAMP] datetime);

insert into @tbl(OPERATOR, PRODUCT, [USER NAME], [TIME STAMP]) values
 (1, 'INS1', '1YHS', '2018-08-15 09:02:33.000')
,(1, 'INS1', '1YHS', '2018-08-15 10:46:17.000')
,(2, 'INS1', '1YHS', '2018-08-15 11:01:28.000')
,(2, 'INS1', '1YHS', '2018-08-15 17:07:47.000');

select OPERATOR, PRODUCT, [USER NAME], [TIME STAMP]
from (
    select OPERATOR, PRODUCT, [USER NAME], [TIME STAMP]
        , row_number() over(partition by PRODUCT, [USER NAME], OPERATOR order by [TIME STAMP]) transId 
    from @tbl) t
order by PRODUCT, [USER NAME], transId, OPERATOR;
```

Comment: Man you are just brilliant!!! I think it is working perfectly. Let me check again. Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Most RDBMS have a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function (a notable exception is MySQL prior to version 8.0):

```
select 
    t.* ,
    row_number() over(order by Product ,Name, TimeStamp) rn
from table t
order by Product, Name, TimeStamp
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt do anything.

Comment: OPERATOR PRODUCT USER NAME TIME STAMP
1 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 09:02:33.000
1 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 10:46:17.000
2 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 11:01:28.000
2 INS1 1YHSG 2018-08-15 17:07:47.000

I have data like this. If the operator is 1, then the license is been purchased at the respective timestamp. If the operator is 2 then the license is released. Here for the 1st license, the 3rd row is the release time and for the 2nd purchased license, 4th row is the release time. I need data to be in this order 1st row, 3rd row, 2nd row and 4th row. Please help.

Comment: @Peak , edit the question add your explanation. Putting an essential info into comments is strongly discouraged at SO.

Comment: @serg, Done. Please check.